# UTF8 string comparisons in MySQL

Tags: mysql, collation, case-sensitive

We have issues with utf8-string comparisons in MySQL 5, regarding case and accents :

from what I gathered, what MySQL implements collations by considering that "groups of characters should be considered equal".

For example, in the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation, all the letters "EÉÈÊeéèê" are in the same box (together with other variants of "e").

So if you have a table containing ["video", "vidéo", "vidÉo", "vidÊo", "vidêo", "vidÈo", "vidèo", "vidEo"] (in a varchar column declared with ut8_general_ci collation) :

- when asking MySQL to sort the rows according to this column, the sorting is random (MySQL does not enforce a sorting rule between "é" and "É" for example),
- when asking MySQL to add a Unique Key on this column, it raises an error because it considers all the values are equal.

What setting can we fiddle with to fix these two points ?

PS : on a related note, I do not see any case sensitive collation for the utf8 charset. Did I miss something ?

---

[edit] I think my initial question still holds some interest, and I will leave it as is (and maybe one day get a positive answer).

It turned out, however, that our problems with string comparisons regarding accents was not linked to the collation of our text columns. It was linked to a configuration problem with the `character_set_client` parameter when talking with MySQL - which defaulted to `latin1`.

Here is the article that explained it all to us, and allowed us to fix the problem :

[Getting out of MySQL character set hell](https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell)

It is lengthy, but trust me, you need this length to explain both the problem and the fix.

Comment: in NCR form, EÉÈÊeéèê are all different. Their values are: E &#201; &#200; &#202; e &#233; &#232; &#234;

Comment: Use `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Link is broken - but InternetArchive has it: http://web.archive.org/web/20141120180423/https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell

Answer (score 1):

Use collation that considers these characters to be distinct. Maybe utf8_bin (it's case sensitive, since it does binary comparison of characters)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: My point is : isn't there a collation which would allow both ? consider these characters distinct AND sort them in a consistent order ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if there is not, you can create your own collation (since MySQL 5.5) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-collation.html

Comment: @LeGEC, Yes the sort order is consistent for `_bin` because the values are distinctly ordered. What do you mean "allow both" when they already do allow both?

Comment: @Pacerier: you are right : sorting in `utf8_bin` will always give the same order ; I was thinking "consistent for humans", though : have `à` greater than `a` and smaller than `b`, `é` greater than `e` and smaller than `d`, etc ... so that sorting by name (for example) gives what the end user would expect.

Comment: @LeGEC, So which collation did you end up using?

Comment: @Pacerier : I ended up using `utf8_general_ci` in MySQL, and sort the data either in the server code (PHP) or in the client code (javascript)

Comment: @LeGEC, If you are going to sort the data in the PHP or JavaScript anyway, then why did you use `utf8_general_ci` instead of `utf8_bin`?