# MySQL wrong order of UTF-8 words

Tags: mysql, sorting, utf-8

When I add UTF-8 words to a table column, and execute an ordered SELECT, the sort order is wrong. On DESC sort, the order is correct but on ASC sort, the order is wrong. How to fix that? Let me explain on example. Lets have a mysql table with Slovak collate:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
   aaa varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci;
```

Now lets insert some values with UTF-8 words:

```
INSERT INTO test (aaa) VALUES
('Leco'),
('Lečo'),
('Ledo'),
('Chovatelstvo'),
('Chovateľstvo')
```

Here is Slovak alphabet explained, you can see which letters are after which other letters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovak_orthography

Now when I select with order, I expect to get the following result:

```
SELECT aaa FROM test ORDER BY aaa ASC
Chovatelstvo
Chovateľstvo
Leco
Lečo
Ledo
```

And I also expect the exactly opposite order for DESC. But here is what I get in fact:

```
SELECT aaa FROM test ORDER BY aaa ASC
Chovateľstvo
Chovatelstvo
Leco
Lečo
Ledo
```

and DESC:

```
SELECT aaa FROM test ORDER BY aaa DESC
Ledo
Lečo
Leco
Chovateľstvo
Chovatelstvo
```

You can see there

```
Chovateľstvo
Chovatelstvo
```

is always in the given order regardless of ASC or DESC. I noticed that if I insert the rows in opposite order, it may end up as

```
Chovatelstvo
Chovateľstvo
```

meaning that the actual order is opposite, but again is the same for ASC and DESC. As like if mysql considered those two letters 'l' and 'ľ' as equal.

I tried this with some older version of MySQL, as well as newest version of MariaDB on another server, the result is the same.

Any idea what causes that and how to fix it?

Comment: Specify the charset and the collation for both column and table

Comment: That doesn't help. I'm going to update the question to reflect that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF8 string comparisons in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023541/utf8-string-comparisons-in-mysql)

Comment: Other very similar question: [MySQL considers 'е' and 'ё' equal, how do I set it to consider them different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297370/mysql-considers-%D0%B5-and-%D1%91-equal-how-do-i-set-it-to-consider-them-different)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the two possible duplicites, however that problem is different. I need slovak collation in order to sort the words properly, and I set the collation already.

Comment: For the Slovak collation those two characters are considered equal (See the [collation table](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_slovak_ci.html)) so the order in which they sort is undefined. If you need them to sort into a distinct order you'll need a different collation. The complete reference is [here](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/by-charset.shtml)

Comment: slovak order is only available for cp852, latin2, cp1250, macce etc.

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 1):

In both the `utf8_slovak_ci` and `utf8_general_ci` collations, the letter `ľ` and the letter `l` are considered the same.

You can see this by observing that this query returns true (1)

```
select _utf8 'Chovateľstvo' collate utf8_slovak_ci = _utf8 'Chovatelstvo'
```

The designers of that collation obviously believe that `ľ` and `l` belong together in the dictionary.  The only collations I can find that do not do that are `latin2_hungarian_ci` and `cp1250_czech_cs`. But to use either one of those  you'll have to change your character set choice.

If you must have them be different, you could try the `utf8_bin` collation. But that will be entirely case sensitive.

The way `ORDER BY` works is basically correct for the rules in the collation.

Maybe there's a defect in the collation?  You could submit a defect report to the MySql team at https://bugs.mysql.com/